# Using glmrob function in R with proportional/percentage Dependent Variable

Tags: r, percentage, glm

I have been utilising the glmrob function in R to depict whether belonging to a certain strategy (3 categories) increases the percentage (0 - 1) of successful reports made. However, my results show coefficients of 2.1+ which I would believe are impossible since the DV can only range from 0-1.

I have run the function with tcc = 1.345 and tcc = 3.5 with no differences in the results. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code, since I have followed what I could find on stack exchange and stack overflow.

```
rob5 <- glmrob(Num_ofSuccess/Total_No_Reports ~ RGamDesStrat3, 
     weights = Total_No_Reports, family = binomial, data = MyMasterThesisDataRSTUDIOV3, 
     method = "Mqle", control = glmrobMqle.control(tcc = 3.5))
```

Example of my code.

```
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          0.5108     0.3266   1.564    0.118    
RGamDesStrat3(0,1]   2.2088     0.4744   4.656 3.22e-06 ***
RGamDesStrat3(1,2]   2.1638     0.4346   4.979 6.40e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Robustness weights w.r * w.x: 
 All 40 weights are ~= 1.
```

However, I would have expected coefficients below the at around 0.3 or 0.4 for both predictors.

Comment: please provide data, just code is useless. read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example